Stripe Payment Vue3
I would like to integrate stripe to charge a user a one-time 20$ payment after successfully  completing a form in my Vue3 application. I've integrated vue-stripe-js and have been able to obtain a token from stripe using the card element in that package, but have been unable to handle submitting the charge to stripe.
Here's the request so far:
    const pay = () => {
      const cardElement = card.value.stripeElement

      elms.value.instance.createToken(cardElement).then((result) => {
        if (result.token) {
          // what should I do with the token to submit a charge for $20 and see it in my stripe dashboard?
          console.log(result.token)
        }
      })
    }

The ideal solution would show me what to do with the token to submit a payment and validate that the other fields in the form have been inputted before the payment is completed. Here's a stackblitz that approximates the problem, thanks so much for sharing your knowledge.

have you read the stripe payment API documentation

Yes I have thx @Bravo but haven't figured out how to apply that to my situation. Thx for any ideas even if it may seem basic to you.

Unfortunately the library you're using is old and only uses the CardElement and tokens which is no longer Stripe's recommended integration path, and soon all token-based integrations will be deprecated(today only cards are still supported). As you can see in https://docs.stripe.com/sdks/community, Stripe recommends using vue-stripe.
As for the integration flow that suits best your use-case, I recommend looking at the deferred flow and just replacing the front-end part with the vue-stripe components.

Thanks so much for the comment. However I cannot use vue-stripe since it doesn't support Vue3, sadly.

When integrating stripe in Vue 3, I did not use a vue-specific stripe library. I used @stripe/stripe-js version 2.2.0. I did the following steps:
I created a composable with the following functions and refs
import { loadStripe as loadStripeLibrary, Stripe, StripeCardElement } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const isStripeLoaded = ref(false);
const stripe = ref<Stripe | null>(null);
const paymentIntent = ref<PaymentIntent>();
const clientSecret = ref('');

export function useBilling() {
  return {
    isStripeLoaded,
    stripe,
    paymentIntent,
    loadStripe,
    loadPaymentIntent,
    createStripeCardUIElement,
    createPaymentMethod,
    submitCardInformation,
  };
}

async function loadStripe() {
  try {
    if (isStripeLoaded.value && stripe.value !== null) {
      return;
    }
    stripe.value = await loadStripeLibrary(publishableKey);
    isStripeLoaded.value = true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

async function loadPaymentIntent(): Promise<void> {
  const response = await axios.get<PaymentIntent>(`/my-intent-url`);
  paymentIntent.value = response.data;
}

async function createPaymentMethod(
  createDto,
) {
  // call to create my record of the payment method
}

function createStripeCardUIElement() {
  clientSecret.value = paymentIntent.value?.client_secret ?? '';
  return stripe.value?.elements({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.value?.client_secret }).create('card');
}

async function submitCardInformation(cardElement: StripeCardElement) {
  return stripe.value?.confirmCardSetup(clientSecret.value, {
    payment_method: {
      card: cardElement,
    },
  });
}


Then inside my component
const stripeCreditCardNumberPlaceholder = ref<HTMLDivElement>();
const cardElement = ref<StripeCardElement>();

async function setupStripe() {
  await loadStripe();
  await loadPaymentIntent();
  createStripeUiElement();
}

// This causes Stripe to inject its UI elements into the template
function createStripeUiElement(): void {
  if (stripeCreditCardNumberPlaceholder.value !== undefined) {
    cardElement.value = createStripeCardUIElement();
    cardElement.value?.mount(stripeCreditCardNumberPlaceholder.value);
  }
}

onMounted(setupStripe);

with simply
<div ref="stripeCreditCardNumberPlaceholder" />

in the template.
I was then just able to use the stripe ref to access all the library's methods, and in my case to submit a setup intent and then handle its response.
